# delete in php after 1 second

Tags: php, sql-delete

I want to delete all the columns from the test_table after 1 second. The code is:

$sql = " DELETE FROM `test_table` WHERE ('timestamp' < '( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)')"

but it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM SystemEvents WHERE ReceivedAt < date_add(current_date, interval -1 day)